# In the Cholesky Factorization, does the spectrum of the individual factors L and L^t tell us anything about the spectrum of the original matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I computed a (*the?*) Cholesky factorization of a 3x3 real, symmetric matrix.  No problem, just a pretty standard computation.

However part (b) asks how could I determine that the original matrix $A$ is positive-definite, by inspecting individual entries of $L$, where $A= LL^t$.

Well, both factors, $L$ and $L^t$, that I computed have positive diagonal entries; of course, taking the transpose keeps the diagonal fixed.  So, I know that both factors have the same, positive eigenvalues, counting multiplicity, etc.

Is this enough to conclude that $A$ is positive-definite?  I.e., is the product of two positive-definite matrices again positive definite?  Basically I can't say 100%, because, although I know, by the multiplicativity of the determinant, $A$ will have positive determinant, but I feel like it's possible for $A$ to  have pairs of negative eigenvalues, too.

Unless...the spectrum of $L$ (and of $L^t$) somehow also determines the spectrum of $A$?  Then we could say for sure, that by inspecting the factors $L$ and $L^t$, we could conclude that $A$ is positive-definite.

What do you think?

Thanks,

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If $A=L L^T$ then $x^T Ax = (L^T x)^2$ so $A$ is positive semidefinite and $A$ is positive definite **iff** $L$ (or $A$) is invertible.

Comment: Yes, I arrived at the same calculation, using just the definitions, too.  But now I see it, by the way you put it.  $L^t$ can't kill any non-vectors, so it must have trivial null-space, i.e., full-rank.  So $L^t$ must be invertible.  But does this fact also make $L$ invertible?  (And consequently A invertible ...) @copper.hat, thanks,

Comment: O yes, their spectrum is the same, since they are similar to one another, I think...@copper.hat, thanks so much,

Comment: One quick follow-up question, before moving on, if you don't mind @copper.hat:  can I give a uniqueness argument for the factor $L$, in this case where $A$ is positive-definite?  (So then $L$, lower triangular, has positive diagonal entries.)  If it's a bit more work, then I will think about it more, but perhaps there's a quick way to show the uniqueness.  What do you think?  Thanks,